# Prototype for interception in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can anyone explain this code to me? Whats the meaning and how to use it?

```
    Function.prototype.createInterceptor = function createInterceptor(fn) {
       var scope = {};
       return function () {
           if (fn.apply(scope, arguments)) {
               return this.apply(scope, arguments);
           }
           else {
               return null;
           }
       };
   };
   var interceptMe = function cube(x) {
           console.info(x);
           return Math.pow(x, 3);
       };
   //
   var cube = interceptMe.createInterceptor(function (x) {
       return typeof x === "number";
   });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is not functional as is, so I made this edit:

```
Function.prototype.createInterceptor = function createInterceptor(fn) {
    var scope = {},
        original = this; //<-- add this
    return function () {
        if (fn.apply(scope, arguments)) {
            return original.apply(scope, arguments);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    };
};
var interceptMe = function cube(x) {
        console.info(x);
        return Math.pow(x, 3);
    };
//
var cube = interceptMe.createInterceptor(function (x) {
    return typeof x === "number";
});
```

The interceptor function validates what is passed to the original function before calling it, and returns `null`
if it didn't see the arguments as valid. If the arguments are valid, then the original function
is called.

```
cube(3) //27 - the argument is valid so the original function is called
cube("asd") //null - Not valid according to the interceptor so null is returned
```

Comment: ohh ic ic....
if (fn.apply(scope, arguments)) {
            return original.apply(scope, arguments);
        }

what about that code? can you expalin it more sppecific? Thanks.

Comment: @user430926 if calling the validator/interceptor function (`fn`), returns a truthy result, then call the original function (`original`) and return it's result. [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is used to pass all arguments around.